# Auto-increment integers for POD items

Tags: list, perl, auto-increment, perl-pod

Would anyone know of a way to dynamically increment an integer for item titles?  This is mainly to avoid having to change every step number in the event that a new step would need to be added/removed somewhere in the middle of a ton of steps.  Below is a small three-step procedure to give you a rough idea of the template structure:

```
=step_wash 1. Wash

<p>Add washing steps here</p>

=cut

# Throw some perl code here to wash stuff

=step_dry 2. Dry

<p>Add drying steps here</p>

=cut

# Throw some perl code here to dry things

=step_fold 3. Fold

<p>Add folding steps here</p>

=cut

# Fold all of the things Perl!
```

Disregarding the item names and structure of this, the goal is to try and eliminate the use of statically numbering the title of each item. I am wondering if there is a possible way to generate an integer that increments; pretty much like replacing 1, 2, 3, etc with something like `{ print $i++ }` instead.. but in POD.

Comment: crosspost on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/1nv2bs/perlpod_ordered_list/)

Comment: You could always generate your pod from a template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POD is pretty Plain and doesn't do that sort of thing.

An extension of POD called PseudoPod in theory does (see https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Pod-PseudoPod/lib/Pod/PseudoPod/Tutorial.pod#Lists) but when I tried it it gave an error.

Comment: @szabgab: search.cpan.org links aren't "stable"?

Comment: That was just an incorrect note for the change. In most cases I changed version specific URLs to "stable" ones, and switched to MetaCPAN in the process.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into POD that allows doing automatic numbering.

I see that you are using custom POD regions which encompass HTML markup, your POD also doesn't look like normal documentation. If you are trying to do *Literate Programming*, there should exist systems that don't require you to write POD. If this is just normal documentation, you should probably remove the HTML, as docs are often viewed via `perldoc` – on the command line.

Sometimes it isn't neccessary to use numbering at all. Bullet points `•` are pretty as well.

Comment: Perhaps I should have provided a bit more background..  Each script represents a procedure which can be both performed manually via the rendered HTML or executed within a GUI written in Java.  The program opens a ticket and displays each item in this case as the abstract of the specific activity and the output within the activity's body.  That's why I threw the disregard line in there as I assumed that would be questioned first :)  Thank you still for confirming that POD doesn't support the auto-numbering functionality.